# VLOOKUP formula to copy entire row values from one Tab to another based on today's date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

HELP! I'm trying to use VLOOKUP to copy an entire row that matches today's date from another tab. Is it possible?

I tried =VLOOKUP(TODAY(),'2023'!A:O,4,0) and I'm not sure how to formulate to include the entire row from sheet 2023. I'm trying to match the date under Column D.

Google Sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19KZGqao_0GUWizUNN52udeueAVCZwkXtW8fpO1k2UTs/edit#gid=0

Comment: `copy an entire row that matches today's date from another tab` If you mean, **display** an entire row on another sheet, then this can be done with a formula. But if you mean, literally, **copy** an entire row then a  formula won't work; you will need to copy/paste from the keyboard, OR use a script.

Comment: Thanks for including your spreadsheet but please don't assume that users will/can/should open your spreadsheet to better understand your question. All this information should be included in the description in the body of your question. In fact, your question doesn't discuss your scenario at all, so it is difficult to offer any answer beyond the above. Also please consider including your data in your question as a markdown table.

Comment: try: `=filter('2023'!A:M,'2023'!D:D=today())` if no match with today's date is found it will throw `#N/A` error.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked @rockinfreakshow